# Why i can't use "this." here?

Tags: c#-4.0, dictionary

I don't understand why this code is wrong, i just want to encapsulate voids in the dictionary.

```
    private delegate void LotIs(string path);

    private Dictionary<int, LotIs> lots = new Dictionary<int, LotIs>
    {
        {0, this.LotIsBanHummer},
        {1, this.LotIsDuck},
        {2, this.LotIsToy},
        {3, this.LotIsDragon},
        {4, this.LotIsMoney}
    };

    private void LotIsBanHummer(string path) 
    {
        lotImage.Image = LB10_VAR7.Properties.Resources.banhammer2;
        StreamReader str = new StreamReader(path + "BunHummer.txt");
        textBox1.Text = str.ReadToEnd();
        textBox3.AppendText(textBox1.Lines[1].Split(' ')[1]);
    }
```

Comment: For the sake of clarifying your texts, please note that there is **no such thing as "a void"**. What you are referring to can be called *functions*, *methods* or *routines*, but speaking of "a void" when referring to a method without a return value is incorrect, just as a method that returns an `int` value is not "an int".

Answer (score 2):

The compiler does not allow you to use `this` in such an initializer expression because `this` is assumed to be uninitialized when the expression is evaluated. Remember that such expressions are evaluated *before* any constructor has been executed.

Within a constructor the use of *this* is permitted at any point even though some fields may not have been initialized yet, either, but there, it is within your responsibility to not access any uninitialized members.

In your case, therefore, the solution is to initialize your dictionary/add the initial contents in your constructor (or, in the case of several constructors, in a method that you call from each constructor).

Answer (score 2):

From the C# specification:

**17.4.5.2
Instance field initialization**

> A variable initializer for an instance field cannot refe rence the
>   instance being created. Thus, it is a compile- time error to reference
>   `this` in a variable initializer, as it is a compile-time error for a
>   variable initializer to reference any instance member through a
>   simple-name

You can move your initialiser to the constructor however.

Answer (score 0):

use `this` in a constructor to define `Dictionary` like that.

like this:

```
private Dictionary<int, LotIs> lots = new Dictionary<int, LotIs>();

public YourClass() {
   lots[0] = this.LotIsBanHummer;
   lots[1] = this.LotIsDuck;
   lots[2] = this.LotIsToy;
   lots[3] = this.LotIsDragon;
   lots[4] = this.LotIsMoney;
}
```

If `LotIsBanHummer`, `LotIsDuck` etc are defined `static` then you can initialize without the `this`.